# How to perform Binding Redirects in Linqpad

Tags: .net-core, linqpad, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a `.linq` file configured as a C# Program.

I reference `Elastic.Apm.NetCallAll` which, in turn references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Absttractions, Version=5.0.0.0` which, as best I can tell, doesn't exist; I can only find references to Version=2.2.0.0.

I guess I need to add a Binding Redirect but I can't figure out *how* to do it for a Linqpad program.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Tick 'Include Prelease' in LinqPad's "Add Nuget...' screen and then click on the down arrow beside the Add To Query button and you should be able to download the correct version.

Comment: Binding redirects won't help - LINQPad has its own version-tolerant assembly resolution mechanism that does not require binding redirects (and ignores them if present). You just need to ensure the right assemblies are referenced (preferably via NuGet)

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't seem to work. I have version 2.2.0.0 installed and associated with this program, but it shows an error saying that it can _only_ find v2.2.0.0 and needs v5